# Kernels and Images

Tags: linear-algebra

For $\dim(V)=n$ and $T \in L(V)$. I am trying to show that for $1 \leq a \leq b$,

$$\ker(T^a) \subseteq ker(T^b) \text{ and } Im(T^b) \subseteq Im(T^a).$$

It is clear to me that if kernel part holds then image will hold too, since $Im+\ker=\dim$, but don't you need more info to find out nullity of a set?

And also that there must exist an integer $m$ such that for some $b$,
$$\ker(T^m)=\ker(T^{m+b}) \text{ and } Im (T^m)=Im (T^{b+m})$$

Comment: Tried my best to understand your intentions. Please proof-read the resulting formulae.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v\in\ker T^a$ be arbitrary. This means that $T^av=0$. Therefore $T^bv=T^{b-a}T^av=T^{b-a}0=0$. We can conclude that $v\in\ker T^b$. This proves the inclusion $\ker T^a\subseteq\ker T^b$.

You can prove the second part using the following outline:

1. Suppose $\ker T^m\neq\ker T^{m+1}$ is true for all $m\in\mathbb N.\qquad(*)$
2. Define $d_m = \dim\ker T^m$. Using the first part of the exercise and the previous point, prove that $(d_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of non-negative integers.
3. Use point 2. and the fact that $\ker T^m\subseteq V$ holds for all $m\in\mathbb N$ to derive a contradiction with the fact that $\dim V=n$. (A little induction might help.)
4. So the assumption $(*)$ had to be false. Conclude that there exists a $m_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $\ker T^{m_0}=\ker T^{m_0+1}$.
5. Using this, you can now show that $\ker T^{m_0}=\ker T^{m_0+b}$ is true for all $b\in\mathbb N$. (This is a bit similar to the first part of the exercise.)